# Get data from past 7 days DB2

Tags: ssis, db2

I have no experience working with DB2 before and I'm kind of stuck in something. I'm working on a project in SSIS reading from DB2 where I write into a flat file. I need to run the process weekly and get data from past 7 days.

My query works this way:

```
Select * From Table
Where ServiceDate >= 2200624 -  7
```

The above query brings data from the past 7 days, but this query don't work for me since I need to execute this process weekly. I need something like this:

```
Select * From Table
Where ServiceDate >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY)
```

The second query throws an error, is there any other way to achieve this? I'm using ODBC source and I was thinking to use a dynamic query in SSIS but I'm not sure how this works in ODBC source, any suggestions or help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
This tables were created a long time ago, so I don't have any information about the data type of these tables.

The actual date 2200624 correspond to 20200624. This is the way that my date shows in the table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error? What data type is ServiceDate? It seems to be an integer and not a DATE

Comment: This is the error that I got:

Vendor Code: -401
Message: [SQL0401] Comparison operator >= operands not compatible. Cause . . . . . :   The operands of comparison operator >= are not compatible. -- Numeric operands are compatible with any other numeric operands and with character and graphic operands. -- Character operands are compatible with operands that are character, graphic, date, time, timestamp, or numeric. -- Date, time, and timestamp operands are compatible with character and graphic operands or with another operand of the same type. Date and timestamp operands are also compatible.

Comment: The Db2 catalog (syscat.columns  or sysibm.syscolumns or qsys2.syscolumns - depending on your Db2-server platform) will show the column datatype (if you search that table for your schema and your tablename , and the ServiceDate column.  EDIT your question with that datatype. What value would be in the first three digits of ServiceDate for year 1999 ?

Answer (score 0):

If ServiceDate is CHAR(7) or equivalent, and if value `2200624` corresponds to YYYYMMDD date 20200624 as per your edited question,  then  the following examples might help.

It assumes ServiceDate values beginning with first character `1` are in the 20th century (`19xx` years), and dates with first character `2` are in the 21st century.

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ( TO_DATE(CASE SUBSTR(ServiceDate,1,1) WHEN '1' THEN  '19'||SUBSTR(ServiceDate,2,6) WHEN '2' THEN '20'||SUBSTR(ServiceDate,2,6) END,'YYYYMMDD')) >= CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS`

This will perform badly, so don't use that!

An alternative that will perform better is to convert `CURRENT DATE - 7 DAYS` into a number that matches your storage-format like this:

`...WHERE ServiceDate >= '2'||substr(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY, 'YYYYMMDD'),2,6)`

and if ServiceDate is INTEGER column datatype then:

`...WHERE ServiceDate >= int('2'||substr(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY, 'YYYYMMDD'),2,6))`

Always state your Db2-server platform (Z/OS, i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows) when asking for help with Db2, because the answer may be different depending on the platform + version of your Db2-server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I ran the code and just bring one row instead of thousand of rows that should supposed to return. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question, to state the Db2 column datatype of ServiceDate ,  and most important, show which actual date corresponds to 2200624

Answer (score 0):

For `ServiceDate` as `YYYYMMDD` INT:

```
Select * From Table
Where ServiceDate >= INT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAY, 'YYYYMMDD'));
```